# How to add strings and text into an input in Python?

Tags: python, string, input, printing

Here is the code:

```
name1 = input("Please enter a name: ")
name1age = int(input("Please enter ", name1, "'s age: "))

name2 = input("Please enter a name: ")
name2age = int(input("Please enter ", name2, "'s age: "))

name3 = input("Please enter a name: ")
name3age = int(input("Please enter ", name3, "'s age: "))

name4 = input("Please enter a name ")
name4age = int(input("Please enter ", name4, "'s age: "))
```

I want the value given for the name to be part of the new input.

Here is the error I'm recieving:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):#
File "\\albyn-sch\data\PupilHome\A.Shahrivar\My Documents\Computing 
Science\Python\Dance Group.py", line 2, in <module>
name1age = int(input("Please enter ", name1, "'s age: "))
TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3
```

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Pass arguments to the `input` as one line. Just replace `,` with `+`. Like this: `input("Please enter " + name1 + "'s age: ")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do string concatenation using `+`. See below:

```
name1 = input("Please enter a name: ")
name1age = int(input("Please enter " + name1 + "'s age: "))
```

This concatenates/joins the three string elements into one and passes it into the input function.

More information can be found [here](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/concatenation/string-concatenation-and-formatting-in-python).

Comment: Works fine for me, please make sure you have copied and pasted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Other alternatives:

You can use string `format` method:

```
name4 = input("Please enter a name ")
name4age = int(input("Please enter {}'s age: ".format(name4)))
```

Or f-strings you you are using python 3.6+:

```
name4 = input("Please enter a name ")
name4age = int(input(f"Please enter {name4}'s age: "))
```

You can also use the modulo operator (`%`) for [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) but IMO format is better.